# RtcPeerConnection on Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, webrtc

I want to create a WebRTC client on an ionic 2 application. 
For this, I use the library RtcPeerConnection.

When I run the application on my laptop with `ionic serve` everything is working but when I launch the application on the smartphone, I have a runtime error during the construction of PeerConnection object.

Here is my constructor of PeerConnection :

`this.pc = new PeerConnection(this.conf, {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});`

And here the error message :

`main.js:76282 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

My error send me to this line in the main.js of the library :

`this.getRemoteStreams = this.pc.getRemoteStreams.bind(this.pc);`

Anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

### EDIT

This post is solved. The PeerConnection class is not supported by Chrome on Android. (According to [jscc.info](http://jscc.info))

Comment: Thats a compatibility issue, what browser are you running it on?

Comment: I run the application on Android smartphone (version 6.0), so I think that Chrome is used (version 57).

Comment: According to http://jscc.info/ Chrome for android does not support PeerConnection Class

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't know this tool to check compatibility. I will use another library to create my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(this.conf);
```

Chrome for Android [*does*](http://caniuse.com/#search=RTCPeerConnection) support RTCPeerConnection. It's still vendor-prefixed however, so you need either [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) (recommended) or something like:

```
let RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
```

Then it [should just work](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/aynr0k5q/).

Comment: Thank you !! I did not have the adapter.js. This solve my problem.